# Map Markers Increase in Size According to Order

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Can anyone advise as to how I should implement a system where the map markers' sizes increase according to their order?

The markers are arranged in order and I would like the latest marker to be the biggest and the others to decrease in size the lower in order they are.

Comment: Have custom marker images, each of a different size.  As you create your markers, change which image you're using for each marker.

Comment: This is fine if you know how many markers you need...

Comment: I need 10 but I dont want to have to create images...loading them all seems to make my map slow - thanks though

Comment: Makes sense. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to use SVG markers. You can scale them as you wish. Here is a quick example with a simple circle marker:

```
var icon = {

    path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: 1
}
```

Note the `scale` property. You can increment this value every time you create a marker.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/88JLY/)</kbd>

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you are still around MrUpsidown, can I apply this to icons that are images?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon You could scale an image too, but this won't be as clean as scaling a SVG...

Answer (score -1):

increment the size of icon marker
that may help